# use would to express imaginary situation without if

Tags: grammar

A native English teacher told me that I cannot use *would* to write about imaginary situation except when I use *if*, like this:

> **If I won the lottery, I would travel around the world.**

Is this structure grammatical when write about an imaginary thing?

> **Building new sports centres would improve public health.**

Comment: I am confused are you saying the 1st sentence is wrong? the second? or both?

Comment: according to the answer below, the second one is wrong in this context, I believe that I should start to learn what is assertive statement.

Comment: I have edited it, as "like this" is usually used before the example, not after. I was trying to find out what you thought, not what other people thought.

Comment: Your English teacher is wrong. There is nothing ungrammatical about either of your sentences.

Comment: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar/will-or-would

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are fine in context, but your teacher is right - the second example is *not* a hypothetical or conditional statement, it is an assertion.

> Building new sports centres would improve public health.

This is a statement of your belief that new sports centres would, for certainty, improve public health. You might make such a statement as part of a firm plan to build sports centres, so there is nothing hypothetical about it.

If you wanted to make a conditional statement it should be:

> If new sports centres were built it would improve public health.

or

> If we built new sports centres, public health would improve.

Similarly, you could change your conditional statement about the lottery win to be an assertion:

> Winning the lottery would mean I could travel around the world.

Comment: No, the English teacher is wrong. The only thing the question describes the teacher as saying is that *would* can only be used in imaginary situations. That is incorrect. (As the grammatical second sentence shows.)

Comment: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar/will-or-would